# How would one fill a specific cell with SQL data using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm new with PHPExcel and very beginner with PHP. I reading alot of examples and but not finding any example that matches close to what I'm doing. This is what I would like my end result to [look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8geEE.jpg).

[image]

So I was able to get PHP excel to extract everything from my SQL database and dumped everything row by row. But I would like the data to be nicely presentable in a sort of box/table/array/section as shown in the image. But in order to achieve the image above should I target each individual cell and have data automatically populated by SQL? Would then PHPexcel recognize that it needs to dump the next record onto the next section?

I was also given advice to try using  `fromArray()` method that can be used to set a whole block of cells in a single call from an array (such as a row read from a database). I am clueless how to get started with this.

If anyone can show me what the code should look like using these methods that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my question.
Here a snippet of my code,

```
    //  SQl database connections
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "IMC_COE2", "IMC123");  
    mysql_select_db("IMC_COE2",$db);  

    $sqlgroups="select client, team_name,support_team_prime,prime_comments,support_team_backup,backup_comments,escalation1,escalation1_comments,escalation2,escalation2_comments,escalation3,escalation3_comments,escalation4,escalation4_comments,note from tbl_address ORDER by team_name";  
    $resultgroups=mysql_query($sqlgroups);  
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($resultgroups);  
        if ($numrows>0)  
        {  
            $count=2;  
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($resultgroups))  
            {  
                $count+=1;  

                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)              
                            ->setCellValue('C3', $data['client'])  
                            ->setCellValue('B2', $data['team_name'])  
                            ->setCellValue('C5', $data['support_team_prime'])  
                            ->setCellValue('D5', $data['prime_comments'])  
                            ->setCellValue('C6', $data['support_team_backup'])  
                            ->setCellValue('D6', $data['backup_comments'])  
                            ->setCellValue('C8', $data['escalation1'])
                            ->setCellValue('D8', $data['escalation1_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C9', $data['escalation2'])
                            ->setCellValue('D9', $data['escalation2_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C10', $data['escalation3'])
                            ->setCellValue('D10', $data['escalation3_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C11', $data['escalation4'])
                            ->setCellValue('D11', $data['escalation4_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('B13', $data['note']); 

            }  
        }
```